# Not able to load basic commands like ls, touch,etc. in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

I am not able to use basic commands like `ls` on my terminal. The following is the steps that I did after which I was not able to use them.

I had uninstalled anaconda using terminal. I used `rm -Rf anaconda` to delete the whole directory. Then I used `open ~/.bash_profile` to delete the path that was created by anaconda. Then I saved the `.bash_profile`. After this step, I was not able to access the basic commands.

So I googled about it. I came up on this link: https://superuser.com/questions/1061765/getting-the-following-error-when-using-ls-in-mac-terminal-bash-ls-command-no?newreg=f6c3fe6862de4085b0ce20a82f0394dd

According to the answers provided. When I type the command `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH` and hit *return*. The commands start working. But when I close my terminal and restart it again, the commands still don't work. I again need to enter the command `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH`. According to the answer, I had to make changes in *.bash_profile* file to load the commands automatically. I did the changes accordingly and still, I was not able to load them directly. This is my .bash_profile currently

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"

export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin
```

I am a newbie to terminal. I am not so familiar with `PATH`. I would be grateful to you if you could help me in some way.

Comment: Your very last assignment to `PATH` overwrites the previous value, because you don't include the old value on the right-hand side. The *only* directory in your `PATH` is `/usr/local/bin`. It's not clear why you have so many assignments in the first place, or why you are adding the same directories multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always type `/bin/ls` (or `/usr/bin/gcc` or `/bin/cp`) and other full paths of standard programs. For example the commands `/bin/ls *.c` or `/bin/pwd` should still work with a faulty `PATH` setting.

Your understanding of `PATH` is wrong. It should contain *several* directories separated by colons `:`. Read wikipage on [PATH (variable)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) and on [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)-s.

You probably want

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin
```

<sup>(the order of entries in `PATH` matters for [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) functions and shells; you could decide to put `$HOME/bin` in front, etc....)</sup>

and you may want to *edit* your `~/.bashrc` (or perhaps `~/.bash_profile` but I recommend `~/.bashrc` because you only want to alter behavior of *interactive* shells) file to add the above line there. BTW those `~/.bash*` files are only read at shell initialization, so you practically need to open a fresh terminal to get them (or restart your shell with e.g. `exec /bin/bash`)

To run your editor, you need to know its name (e.g. `vim`, `emacs`, `nano` ....) and find its path. Sometimes the `EDITOR`  environment variable is correctly set (so try `/bin/echo $EDITOR` and see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)). BTW, you might use the `/usr/bin/find` command for that. For example, if you are familiar with `emacs` you might run `/usr/bin/emacs $HOME/.bashrc`

Notice that `$HOME` or `$EDITOR` is (like `$PATH` in your question) *expanded* by the shell. Read about [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) in `bash`, and read about [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)

See also [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: What is the difference between placing the :$PATH in the beginning of the path (export PATH=$PATH/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin) or at the end of the path(export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH)? And why do I need to place $PATH, what does it represent?

Comment: I did not wrote `$PATH` but `$HOME`

Answer (score 0):

Your paths are wrong. Run this command in Terminal:

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Comment: the doublequotes are not needed

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch They don't hurt, either, since `~` isn't used anywhere.